# Coded UI Test change user causes FatalExecutionEngineError returning a AgentRestart.dat

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, automated-tests

**Issue:**
I'm running a Coded UI Test with [CUITe](https://cuite.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) in VS 2012 Update in C#. 
QA agent is falling over and producing a dat file

running in Debug mode 
It successfully opens the IE browser window , logs in, attempts to change user in a combo box. the format for these names are 'Mr First Last (username)'

```
CUITe_HtmlComboBox cboUsers = bw.Get<HtmlComboBox>("Id~user");
string terminatingString = ")";
int i = -1;
foreach(string userPart in cboUsers.Items) //'Mr'
{
    if(userPart.EndsWith(terminatingString))
    {    
        if(userPart.Contains("username"))
            cboUsers.SelectItem(i);
        i++;
    }

}
```

**Logs**
During debugging VS will throw this

```
FatalExecutionEngineError was detected
Message: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. 
The address of the error was at 0x69c08d3b, on thread 0x1410. 
The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. 
Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
```

Running through MSTest.exe there is a AgentRestart.dat as follows ( apologies for the

```
    ÿÿÿÿ          sMicrosoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.AgentObject, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a   7Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Agent.AgentRestartInfo   m_runIdm_testsCompleted System.Guid   ýÿÿÿSystem.Guid   _a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_j_k           ÂTíÚi©D¹È›ë¤÷
```

I'm working through the Managed Debugging Assistants. As the debugging is done in the Test Explorer it may not get called. I've kept the code to a minimum, and will include more if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, couldn't connect to the 
telnet ip port for the [data source](http://www.postseek.com/meta/0f317c4231d22f2b60e6150212f0d615)